# Node JS error "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, node-mysql

I'm having trouble in accessing MYSQL.

There is a GET METHOD at my code below :

```
    app.get('/users',function(request,response){
    client.query('select * from User where 1=1',function(error,result){
        if(error){
            response.json('unfortunately fail');
            console.log('unfortunately fail , error : %s',error);
            console.log('error stack: %s',error.stack);
            console.log('error message: %s',error.message);
            throw error;
        }else{
            console.log('select success....');
            response.json('select success....');
            response.json(result);
        }
    });
});
```

When that method is executed, there is an error :

```
 unfortunately fail , error : Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
error stack: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
at Protocol._enqueue (/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:123:18)
at Connection._implyConnect (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:417:10)
at Connection.query (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:199:8)
at app.listen.host (/web.js:70:10)
at callbacks (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
at param (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
at pass (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
at Router._dispatch (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
```

And this is about the variables (express, mysql ...)

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var client = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'http://nodejs.somewhere.com/WebMysql',
    port : 3306,
    user : 'user',
    password : 'password',
    database  : 'database'
});
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: I think it's not about code issue... isn't it?

Comment: Should I check whether mysql is running? then how?

Comment: a psycho downgraded my question!

Answer (score 1):

Your `host` setting for your mysql database connection is incorrect (`ENOTFOUND` for getaddrinfo means DNS resolution failed). It needs to be just the hostname of the mysql server (e.g. `nodejs.somewhere.com`).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but would you explain me more easily? You mean not domain address but the ID?

Comment: 'http://nodejs.somewhere.com/WebMysql' is just the example domain, real domain is different. Do you mean this?

Comment: The mysql server has to be running somewhere (on port 3306). The `host` setting is the hostname/IP address of that server. For example, many web apps are located on the same machine as the mysql server so they would use `'localhost'`.

Comment: No, `nodejs.somewhere.com/WebMysql` is a URL, not a hostname. The `nodejs.somewhere.com` is the hostname.

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't know that thank you.  'nonodejs.somewhere.com/WebMysql' is the GUI page of myPhpAdmin. so I did fix it to 'nonodejs.somewhere.com' and 'localhost' but neither of them works sadly.

Comment: Ok brother, I think I found one. The error above does not occurs but another error happens , it's 503 Service Unavailable error. what do you think? is it going right?

Comment: Most mysql server installations only listen on localhost out of the box, so that's not unexpected. So instead of changing the mysql server to listen for connections from the internet, you should probably either relocate your node app to the same server or find some way to tunnel through (e.g. forward mysql connections over ssh).